# Starobinsky inflation in Supergravity

Tags: cosmological-inflation, supergravity

The available experimental data prefers plateau models of cosmic inflation, and among them Starobinsky inflation (aka R^2 inflation) is preferred, even if maybe not significantly. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Starobinsky+model+of+cosmic+inflation) for summary and pointers.

Since Starobinsky inflation is pure gravity (the inflaton field here is an effective incarnation of a higher gravitational curvature correction), it lends itself to embedding into supergravity models. There are some claims that the match of Starobinsky inflation to data further improves after embedding into supergravity.

For instance Alexandre-Houston-Mavromatos claim that under mild (?) assumptions gravitino condensation produces just the right Starobinsky potential ([here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Starobinsky+model+of+cosmic+inflation#CompatibilityWithsusybreaking)), while Dalianis-Farakos claim that a problem with the size of the initial homogeneous patch goes away after embedding into supergravity ([here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Starobinsky+model+of+cosmic+inflation#ShrinkingOfInitialHomogeneousPatch)).

Clearly there are assumptions going into such statements. It would be good to have some feeling as to how robust these are. Does anyone here have further insight on this? I'd be grateful for comments and pointers.

Comment: If you do not get a response here you could try over at a mostly theoretical site  http://www.physicsoverflow.org/questions/main

Comment: Yes, I am aware of PhysicsOverflow, I am a co-moderator of that site. Unfortunately it still does not have too many participants. I had tried a similar question to the one above last year there, without getting any replies: http://physicsoverflow.org/26235/starobinsky-inflation-and-supergravity